# How to list all files within a directory and all its sub-directories

Tags: java, list, directory

I've made a program that lists all file names in a desired directory of your extension choice. Now I want to and I don't know how to change it to list all files within sub-directories too. Do you have any ideas? Here's my code. Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String str[]){
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("1.Enter directory name:");
            String adress = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("2.Enter file extension:");
            String exten = br.readLine();

            File directory = new File(adress);

            File[] f = directory.listFiles();     

            List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> valid = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0; i < f.length; i++){
                if(f[i].isFile()){
                    files.add(f[i].getName());
                }
            }

            for(int i=0; i < files.size(); i++){
                if (files.get(i).endsWith(exten)){
                    valid.add(files.get(i));
                }
            }

            for(int i=0; i < valid.size(); i++){
                int pos = valid.get(i).lastIndexOf(".");
                    names.add(valid.get(i).substring(0, pos));
                    System.out.println(names.get(i));
            }
       }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? With Java 7 you can use a FileVisitor, with Java 8 there is a built-in method and you could probably write all your code in two lines.

Comment: Read up on recursion because this is what you will want to use. You'll need to create your own method and not just use a main method for this to work.

Comment: Please learn to use enhanced for loops. You should use the `File` API properly, using the `FileFilter` would help you. As far as your main question - you need to recurse.

Comment: Thank you all for replies. I've just recently started learning JAVA so i didn't know about enhanced loops. Will use from now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Java 7 or 8 you could use the [FileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html), but in Java 7 it means writing more then one line of code. If not and you want to keep it simple, [Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) may be your friend.

```
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(path, new String[]{"xlxs"}, true);
```

Comment: `Files.walk(Paths.get(".")).filter((path) -> path.toString().endsWith(".java")).forEach(System.out::println);` is one line by my count.

Comment: Yes, I agree, and it's a very good sample for Java 8! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made this awhile back to find all of *.xls or *.xlsx in a directory.

Hope this will help you with your question.

```
public static List<String> fileSearch(String d){
        List<String> filesFound = new ArrayList<String>();
        File dir = new File(d);
        try{
        for(File file: dir.listFiles()){
            if(file.isFile() && (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx") || file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls"))){

                long filesize = file.length();
                long fileSize = filesize / 1024;

                filesFound.add(d + "\\" + file.getName());
                System.out.println("Added: " + d + "\\" + file.getName()  + "     " + fileSize + " KB" );
            }else if(file.isDirectory() && !file.isHidden()){
                System.out.println("Found Directory: " + file.getName());
                filesFound.addAll(fileSearch(d + "\\" + file.getName()));
            }else if(isRoot(file)){
                        //DO NOTHING
            }
        }

        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            return filesFound;
        }
    }

private static boolean isRoot(File file){
        File[] roots = File.listRoots();

        for (File root : roots) {
            if (file.equals(root)) {
            return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

What this does, it will search every file for a match and if it matches then it will add it to the array "filesFound" from there you can get all the paths of matched files. BUT for you, you would take out the .xlsx and .xls part and add in your ext.

```
fileSearch(String d, String ext)
```

and change the if then to:

```
if(file.isFile() && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(ext))
```

ALSO i have it outputting when ever it finds a match with the file size next to it. The file size is just a visual aid and does not get included in the array.

Comment: This is very antiquated and not only a little messy. See the other suggested solutions.

Comment: Could be messy, I made it a year ago and does exactly what i want it to do and what he wants to do... that is with a little tweaking.  It goes though every single folders it finds and every file from the directory and on. but back then i had limited knowledge on the file system

Comment: Java 7 was released `2011-07-28`. Sorry but; there is no excuse for this.